# Something wrong with my toggleclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is something wrong with my jQuery script. It kinda works, but when I try to toggle between the classes it works at first.
the script changes classes just like it's supposed to. but when i try to do it again,
I have to click the link and then somewhere else, and then it works again.
I want to be able do repeat the whole procedure over and over without having to click two extra times.

```
var clickOnSettings = true;
$(".settings_link").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (clickOnSettings) {
        $("#coverup").toggleClass("cover1");
        $("#settingani").toggleClass("settings1");
        clickOnSettings = false;
    }
});
$("#coverup").click(function () {
    if (!clickOnSettings) {
        $("#coverup").toggleClass("cover2");
        $("#settingani").toggleClass("settings2");
        clickOnSettings = true;
    }
});
```

created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dzt1v6f/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you toggle 'cover1', you basically toggle between having and not having 'cover1' on the element. That does not imply that you automatically get `cover2` when you remove `cover1`.

You have to do that yourself. Fortunately, `toggleClass` has a second parameter that accepts a boolean. This allows you to easily toggle classes on or off based on your conveniently introduced boolean.

Furthermore, this makes the click handler for both elements the same:

```
var clickOnSettings = false;
$( ".settings_link, #coverup" ).click(function() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    clickOnSettings = ! clickOnSettings;
    //Toggle all classes.
    $( "#coverup" ).toggleClass( "cover1", clickOnSettings);
    $( "#settingani" ).toggleClass( "settings1", clickOnSettings);
    $( "#coverup" ).toggleClass( "cover2", !clickOnSettings);
    $( "#settingani" ).toggleClass( "settings2", !clickOnSettings);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dzt1v6f/20/

Comment: I understand how you did, but it did not work in my case.
the div just enterd end exited in under 0.2s.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that. I've rewritten the whole answer so now the code is shorter, cleaner and doesn't have that artifact anymore. I removed the old code snippet, since it is sub-optimal compared to this one.

Comment: This worked like a charm. have been stuck with this for a while. Big thanks for the help! =)

Comment: notised that this did not work either. but i posted an answer, many thanks for the help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `addClass` and `removeClass` for what you want to do.

```
var clickOnSettings = true;

            $( ".settings_link" ).click(function() { 
                event.preventDefault();
                if (clickOnSettings) {
                    $( "#coverup" ).addClass( "cover1" );
                    $( "#settingani" ).addClass( "settings1" );
                    $( "#coverup" ).removeClass( "cover2" );
                    $( "#settingani" ).removeClass( "settings2" );
                    clickOnSettings = false;
                }
            });
            $( "#coverup" ).click(function() { 
                if (!clickOnSettings) {
                    $( "#coverup" ).addClass( "cover2" );
                    $( "#settingani" ).addClass( "settings2" );
                    $( "#coverup" ).removeClass( "cover1" );
                    $( "#settingani" ).removeClass( "settings1" );
                    clickOnSettings = true;
                }
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dzt1v6f/15/

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it!**

Not the prettiest code. But this worked I needed to have another class for the settingani and not for the coverup. So I had to do it like this:

```
        var clickOnSettings = 1;

        $( ".settings_link" ).click(function() { 
            event.preventDefault();
            if (clickOnSettings == 1) {
                $( "#settingani" ).removeClass( "settings0" );
                $( "#coverup" ).addClass( "cover1" );
                $( "#settingani" ).addClass( "settings1" );
                clickOnSettings = 3;
            }
        });
        $( ".settings_link" ).click(function() { 
            event.preventDefault();
            if (clickOnSettings == 2) {
                $( "#coverup" ).removeClass( "cover2" );
                $( "#settingani" ).removeClass( "settings2" );
                $( "#coverup" ).addClass( "cover1" );
                $( "#settingani" ).addClass( "settings1" );
                clickOnSettings = 3;
            }
        });
        $( "#coverup" ).click(function() { 
            if (clickOnSettings == 3) {
                $( "#coverup" ).removeClass( "cover1" );
                $( "#settingani" ).removeClass( "settings1" );
                $( "#coverup" ).addClass( "cover2" );
                $( "#settingani" ).addClass( "settings2" );
                clickOnSettings = 2;
            }
        });
```

Thanks for all the help! =)